# SQL Results group by month

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to return some results spread over a rolling 12 month period eg:

```
MONTH       IN   OUT
January    210    191
February   200    111
March      132    141
April      112    141
May        191    188 
etc...
```

How do I spread the results over a date range, populating the first column with the month name?

IN MSSQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT  COUNT(problem.problem_type = 'IN') AS IN, 
    COUNT(problem.problem_type = 'OUT') AS OUT, 
    DATEPART(year, DateTime) as Year,
    DATEPART(month, DateTime) as Month
FROM problem
WHERE   (DateTime >= dbo.FormatDateTime('2010-01-01')) 
    AND 
    (DateTime < dbo.FormatDateTime('2010-01-31'))
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, DateTime),
    DATEPART(month, DateTime);
```

But this is against an Oracle database so DATEPART and DateTime are not available.

My Problem table is roughly:

```
problem_ID Problem_type   IN_Date                     OUT_Date
   1           IN        2010-01-23 16:34:29.0       2010-02-29 13:06:28.0
   2           IN        2010-01-27 12:34:29.0       2010-01-29 12:01:28.0
   3           OUT       2010-02-13 13:24:29.0       2010-09-29 15:04:28.0
   4           OUT       2010-02-15 16:31:29.0       2010-07-29 11:03:28.0
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.problem_type = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IN, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.problem_type = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUT, 
         TO_CHAR(datetime, 'YYYY') AS year,
         TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MM') AS month
    FROM PROBLEM p
   WHERE p.DateTime >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
     AND p.DateTime < TO_DATE('2010-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datetime, 'YYYY'), TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MM')
```

You could also use:

```
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.problem_type = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IN, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN p.problem_type = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OUT, 
         TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MM-YYYY') AS mon_year
    FROM PROBLEM p
   WHERE p.DateTime >= TO_DATE('2010-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
     AND p.DateTime < TO_DATE('2010-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datetime, 'MM-YYYY')
```

Reference:

- [TO_CHAR](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)
- [TO_DATE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Why can't we use 'group by mon_year'? MySQL allows use of alias column name in group clause.

Comment: @Scott Chu: Oracle does not allow use of column alias in the Group clause. You must manually match the expression used in the column. Mileage may vary with other DBs.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want something like

```
SELECT SUM( (CASE WHEN problem_type = 'IN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) in,
       SUM( (CASE WHEN problem_type = 'OUT' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ) out,
       EXTRACT( year FROM DateTime ) year,
       EXTRACT( month FROM DateTime ) month
  FROM problem
 WHERE DateTime >= date '2010-01-01'
   AND DateTime < date '2010-01-31'
 GROUP BY EXTRACT( year FROM DateTime ),
          EXTRACT( month FROM DateTime )
```

Comment: Group by extract doesn't seem to work on Oracle 10. Not sure if I'm using it right.