# oracle count based on month

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to write Oracle SQL.

I am looking for solution something similar. Please find below data I have

```
start_date      end_date        customer 
01-01-2012      31-06-2012      a 
01-01-2012      31-01-2012      b  
01-02-2012      31-03-2012      c
```

I want the count of customer in that date period. My result should look like below

```
Month   : Customer Count 
JAN-12  :  2 
FEB-12  :  2 
MAR-12  :  2 
APR-12  :  1 
MAY-12  :  1 
JUN-12  :  1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Results group by month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138371/sql-results-group-by-month)

Comment: Not really. This one intends to count 1/1 - 30/6 across 6 months, once of each month. There probably is a duplicate, but that's not it

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to generate the months separately in another query and join that to your data table (note that I'm assuming that you intended customer A to have an end-date of June 30, 2012 since there is no June 31).

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  with mnths as(
  2    select add_months( date '2012-01-01', level - 1 ) mnth
  3      from dual
  4   connect by level <= 6 ),
  5  data as (
  6    select date '2012-01-01' start_date, date '2012-06-30' end_date, 'a' customer from dual union all
  7    select date '2012-01-01', date '2012-01-31', 'b' from dual union all
  8    select date '2012-02-01', date '2012-03-31', 'c' from dual
  9  )
 10  select mnths.mnth, count(*)
 11    from data,
 12         mnths
 13   where mnths.mnth between data.start_date and data.end_date
 14   group by mnths.mnth
 15*  order by mnths.mnth
SQL> /

MNTH        COUNT(*)
--------- ----------
01-JAN-12          2
01-FEB-12          2
01-MAR-12          2
01-APR-12          1
01-MAY-12          1
01-JUN-12          1

6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH TMP(monthyear,start_date,end_date,customer) AS (
  select LAST_DAY(start_date),
         CAST(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1) AS DATE),
         end_date,
         customer
  from data
  union all
  select LAST_DAY(start_date),
         CAST(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, 1) AS DATE),
         end_date,
         customer
  from TMP
  where LAST_DAY(end_date) >= LAST_DAY(start_date)
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(MonthYear, 'MON-YY') TheMonth,
       Count(Customer) Customers
FROM TMP
GROUP BY MonthYear
ORDER BY MonthYear;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/28c5d/16/0)